# Несколько фильтров на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, фильтрация

Использую Яндекс map api -> ObjectManager. Возник вопрос по фильтрации меток несколькими фильтрами.

Поставил 4 фильтра на карту по примеру из песочницы. Каждый фильтр работает как надо, только нет связанности между ними. Т.е. если фильтровать по одному, а потом по другому фильтру, результат второго затирает фильтрацию первого.

Как сделать, чтобы фильтры работали совместно?

Answer (score 1):

Фильтры можно объединять через логические условия, вот [пример в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__setFilter)

`objectManager.setFilter('properties.type == "кафе" || properties.type == "аптека"');`